# Name for a small, central unit of human memory

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, nouns

I am having trouble coming up with the word to describe a small memory which stands out amongst others.  I thought of the word 'aphorism', describing a small and concise phrase, but I'm searching for a word more directly related to memory and in any concise, strong way - like an object, picture, or sound that can trigger or best capture the memory of a whole day or event.

Thank you for any input on this!

Edit: A phrase is fine, but a single word is ideal.

Comment: Perhaps, a *vivid memory* of some experience or point in time.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but I'm specifically looking for a single word.  Updating question.

Comment: Something like a flashback?

Comment: A *seminal* memory is often used to refer a vivid memory of an influential or personality defining event.

Comment: A reminiscence ?

Comment: +1 Good question. In fact, *memory* is also used in precisely the sense you asked for. Consider *memories*: individual items one remembers.

Comment: This question needs to be closed as unclear.

Comment: @JoeBlow what's unclear?

Comment: @568ml it seems to be asking both for a word for a memory and for an object that triggers the memory; it isn't entirely clear which is really wanted.

Comment: @Jules ah yes I see what you mean now. I agree that it's unclear.

Comment: Vignette is an archaic sense of precisely what the OP asked for.  So few people are active diarists or letter writers, that use of vignette in this sense is fast being forgotten.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Technically, it would be ***[engram](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/engram)***:

> A physical alteration thought to occur in living neural tissue in response to stimuli, posited as an explanation for memory.

[A better explanation:](http://www.evl.uic.edu/sugimoto/memRem.html)

> Associative retrieval is an automatic reminding process. It occurs when a cue automatically triggers an experience of remembering. Strategic retrieval is a slow deliberate search of memory to generate hints and cures. Strategic retrieval interrogates the automatic retrieval process.
>
> Encoding the experience strengthen the connections between groups of neurons. The resulting transient or enduring changes in our brains are called engrams. **The engram is the representation of a memory in the brain.** A retrieval cue induces a pattern of activity: if this pattern is similar to a previously encoded pattern you remember the event.

---

Non-technically, it would be *[reminiscence](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/reminiscence)*:

> - an event that brings to mind a similar, former event.
> - an event, phenomenon, or experience that reminds one of something else.
> - the act or process of recalling the past.
> - a mental impression retained and recalled from the past.

Comment: Probably the best answer. ie, if we asked 20 neural researchers, I bet 15 would say "well we use engram for that, but given that nobody has a clue yet about consciousness or brain functioning" and five flakey new-age fringe researchers would say "Mnemon!"  :)  that's my guess anyway

Comment: Mnemon is a theoretical word and I couldn't find any scientific explanation for that.

Answer (score 7):

**[Mnemon](http://medicine.academic.ru/87110/mnemon)**   a theoretical fundamental unit of memory

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I am looking for.  I am also interested if there are words which mean something very similar to this, but (for a lack of a better way of saying it), sounds cooler.

Comment: A synonym? Doing a 'Artaxerxes II' ;-)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_humorous_units_of_measurement

Comment: And this one: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unusual_units_of_measurement I like the idea of doing a 'smoot' and if you are damn creative you could apply it to memory

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/170330/word-describing-the-smallest-amount-possible/170344#170344 a similar discussion

Comment: @Third, you're going **way too far** to state blankly that it is "a theoretical fundamental U.o.M."  Rather, let's say something like "some researchers and others are now using the term 'Mnemon' for just the concept the OP asks about."

Comment: @Joe Blow a quote is a quote is a quote

Comment: However, this does not factor the 'trigger' concept. I am not sure how the OP has accepted the answer. *Mnemon* is a formal technical term for nothing more than 'memory' in the sense I quoted in my answer. In general English writing, *Mnemon* would sound so out of place.

Comment: @ThirdNews And when you have a good quote, it's because it's quoted! http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aX6XMIldkRU

Comment: @JoeBlow - mnemon is not derivative of "meme".  The term "mnemonic", for example, [dates back to the 1600s, and is derivative of the Greek "mnemon"](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mnemonic).

Comment: @Galactic - you are 1000% correct!  Sorry, I was pretty drunk.

Answer (score 2):

***(a) [memory](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/memory)***

> **2** Something remembered from the past: *one of my earliest memories is of sitting on his knee*

That 'something' corresponds pretty well to the OP's idea of "a small memory … like an object, picture, or sound."

However, I would definitely prefer a more specific term for the kind of "trigger" that evokes a whole episode.  Let's see what the other have to say.

Comment: I ignored the trigger part of the question, since it seemed confusing and irrelevant. The (theoretical) small, central "basic unit" of, "quantum of" human memory seems to be referred to by one of the two words in the answers here; and sometimes some others.  Daniel Dennett books, for instance, would be the perfect source here (I forgot what Dennett currently uses for this term).  (Dennett is not as good as Dawkins at making incredibly catchy words/phrases - Dennet is always trying to come up with something as catchy as his buddy Dawkins, but he has not got there yet :) )

Comment: @JoeBlow However, the trigger is the central point of OP's question, it's not just any item of memory but one that brings up related memories.

Answer (score 2):

Try *recollection*. This word refers to the things brought back by memory.

*Mnemon* and *engram* intend to refer to insignificant, atomic units, not something like a mental picture.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that **evocation** works, especially if it is emotional.

> the act of bringing something into the mind or memory : the act of
>   evoking something

If it is an object, words, picture, and so on then a good term is [mnemonic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mnemonic).

Comment: this would seem to be unrelated to the question

Comment: dude a mnemonic is when you use some trick, to remember something.  it's not a "unit of memory".

Comment: @JoeBlow - a mnemonic triggers a memory.  He is not asking for a memory unit.  He is asking what is the object called that triggers a memory.  Please read question.

Comment: you know what, **you are totally correct**.  Actually, the question is complete crap and wasting our time. The problem is the heading says one thing (extremely clearly) and the tail of the question says something utterly different (very clearly).  Thanks for pointing this out, Rye.

Comment: @JoeBlow - I did have to read it three times.

Comment: I feel bad because I often don't read to the end of questions. ("Life's too short" principle.) Thanks for clearing it up!

Answer (score 1):

The type of memory event that involves a discrete stimuli evoking a flood of strong memories is called *redintegration* or *redintegrative memory.*

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redintegration